# PostFix to PreFix/Infix Conversion JAVA. "Return value of the method is never used" error. String return type recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, stack, binary-tree, return-type

I am in the process of creating a Binary Expression Tree, converting a PostFix expression to Infix/PreFix expressions. I am having trouble with returning the  String type recursive methods for the: *display (printing out the BXT in a nice format), postfix, prefix, and infix traversal methods*. I keep getting the following message: "Return value of the method is never used." and the IDE keeps wanting me to change the return type to void. Why is this?

I honestly am not seeing how this is even possible because I verified that my tree was built correctly, and the issue only comes with the return type being String (we have to use String return type). I tried different ways (as you can see by the code), but I'm just not seeing the logic why it's not returning the String that was recursively built with the helper method.

Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class BXT {
private int count;
private TreeNode root;

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return root == null;
}

//BXT Constructor
public BXT() {
    count = 0;
    root = null;
}

//method that builds the tree out of text argument passed to it
public void buildTree(String text) {

    StringTokenizer stringText = new StringTokenizer(text);
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();

    while (stringText.hasMoreElements()) {
        String nextToken = stringText.nextToken();
        if (nextToken.compareTo("-") == 0 || nextToken.compareTo("+") == 0 ||
                nextToken.compareTo("*") == 0 || nextToken.compareTo("/") == 0) {
            TreeNode operator = new TreeNode(nextToken);
            operator.setRight(stack.pop());
            operator.setLeft(stack.pop());
            stack.push(operator);
        } else
            stack.push(new TreeNode(nextToken));
    }
    root = stack.pop();
}

//method that displays the BXT
public String display() {
    return displayHelper(root, 0);
}

//helper method for display
public String displayHelper(TreeNode displayNode, int level) {
    String concat = "";
    if (displayNode == null)
        return "";
    concat += displayHelper(displayNode.getRight(), level + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++)
        concat += "\t";
    concat += displayNode.getValue().toString() + "\n";
    concat += displayHelper(displayNode.getLeft(), level + 1);
    return concat;
}

//method that displays the postFix traversal
public String postfix() {
    String post;
    post = postFixOrder(root);
    return post;
}

//helper method for displaying postfix order traversal
public String postFixOrder(TreeNode postFixOrder) {
    if (postFixOrder == null)
        return "";
    else {
        return postFixOrder(postFixOrder.getLeft()) + postFixOrder(postFixOrder.getLeft()) + postFixOrder.getValue().toString();
    }
}

//method that displays the inFix traversal
public String infix() {
    return inFixOrder(root);
}

//helper method for displaying infix order traversal
public String inFixOrder(TreeNode inFixOrder) {
    if (inFixOrder == null)
        return "";
    else {
        return inFixOrder(inFixOrder.getLeft()) + inFixOrder.getValue().toString() + inFixOrder(inFixOrder.getRight());
    }
}

//method that displays the prefix traversal
public String prefix() {
    return preFixOrder(root);
}

//helper method for displaying prefix order traversal
public String preFixOrder(TreeNode preFixOrder) {
    if (preFixOrder == null)
        return "";
    return (preFixOrder.getValue().toString() + " ") + preFixOrder(preFixOrder.getLeft()) + preFixOrder(preFixOrder.getRight());
}
```

Comment: Could it be that in the place you call `display()` you aren't using the value there?  Although it seems your IDE is being dumb; these are public methods and it can't know how other classes might use them.

Comment: In my driver class, all I have written is the following:             System.out.println("BXT: "); tree.display(); | That's it. The method called should return a string that was recursively built to display the BXT.... ughh

Comment: Perhaps try ` System.out.println(tree.display());` so the String is used somewhere?

Comment: ..... omg. i've been staring at this for so long I forgot that was an option... ahahahahaha..... thank you!